# Autorotate view inside UITabBarController and UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My main view controller is a `UITabBarController`, with 4 `UINavigationControllers` as the tab bar items.  Each navigation bar is a couple of different views that get pushed onto it's stack.

I have a single view that I want autorotated, but I can't get `willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation` to be called within that view controller.

I've tried subclassing my `UITabBarController` and `UINaviationControllers` and adding an override for `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` like so:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

Even after that I can't get the view to rotate.  I figured maybe the top-most `UIViewController` (tab and navigation included) has to be able to rotate. Or even every view up the chain.  I've tried overriding `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` for every controller but still can't get the view to rotate.

Anyone accomplished this or have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Besides subclassing your tabBarController as you did overriding houldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, you must do the following:

In the viewDidLoad method of the controller in which you want to add a view to be rotated:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Add this delegate method in the controller in which you want to add a view to be rotated:

```
 - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    //NSLog(@"didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation");


    if((fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
       (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
    {    

        YourAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [mainDelegate.tabBarController.view addSubview: viewToBeRotated];

    [viewToBeRotated setHidden:NO];

    return;

}

if(fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    [viewToBeRotated removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view setHidden:NO];
}
```

}

You may also want to add the following method:

```
- (void)willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
    //self.view = self.portrait;
    YourAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [viewToBeRotated removeFromSuperview];
    mainDelegate.tabBarController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    mainDelegate.tabBarController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(0));
    mainDelegate.tabBarController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 480.0);

}
else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
    YourAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [mainDelegate.tabBarController.view addSubview: viewToBeRotated];
    mainDelegate.tabBarController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    mainDelegate.tabBarController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(-90));
    mainDelegate.tabBarController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 460.0, 320.0);
}
else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{


//self.view = self.portrait;
        YourAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [viewToBeRotated removeFromSuperview];
        mainDelegate.tabBarController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        mainDelegate.tabBarController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(180));
        mainDelegate.tabBarController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 480.0);
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        YourAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [mainDelegate.tabBarController.view addSubview: viewToBeRotated];
        mainDelegate.tabBarController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        mainDelegate.tabBarController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
        mainDelegate.tabBarController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 460.0, 320.0);
    }
}
```

You may also want to take a look at

[Rotating the iPhone, and instantiating a new UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730799/rotating-the-iphone-and-instantiating-a-new-uiviewcontroller)

[TabBarController and navigationControllers in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756536/tabbarcontroller-and-navigationcontrollers-in-landscape-mode-episode-ii)

Comment: I'm actually swapping out two views.  I tried setting the autoResizingMask, but it still doesn't work.  The other two methods you suggest should be taken care of by my - willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation method.  It swaps out self.view based on the orientation.  That method never even gets called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SubClassed `UITabBarController` (or use an addition) that asks the selected navigationController for the `visibleViewController`'s response to rotation request:

```
@implementation RotatingTabBarController
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        if([self.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
           return [[(UINavigationController*)self.selectedViewController visibleViewController] shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
        } else {
           return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
        }
}
@end
```

Comment: oops, only saw now that this is an old question

Comment: subclassing UITabBarController is discouraged by apple.

Answer (score 0):

subclassing UITabBarController and overriding this method worked:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

I think my real problem was XCode not compilingthe updated code.  I did Build clean, touch and restarted XCode and the simulator and the changes finally took.

Comment: This would let all view controllers to be rotate-able, I guess.