# Issue with UIViewController implementation not calling didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation on rotate

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4, mpmovieplayer

I've implemented a class inheriting form UIViewController. I used xib editor to create the portrait orientation of the Titlebar and Toolbar and those rotate correctly when I rotate the iPad. However I have a MPMoviePlayerController which I want to resize manually using this method:

```
-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    _mvp.view.frame = CGRectMake(_titlebar.frame.origin.x , _titlebar.frame.origin.y + _titlebar.frame.size.height , _titlebar.frame.size.width , super.view.frame.size.height  - 2* 44); 
    [_mvp stop];
}
```

_mvp is my MPMoviePlayerController. I resize using this method earlier in the app and have no issue so I don't understand why this method isn't called? (as the movie also continues playing) I have implemented shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation to return YES - does that prevent this being run in any way?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit return while writing it and it just posted :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you have a parent controller that does not manually pass the method call from **didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation** to the child controllers. If you use a UINavigationController or UITabBarController as your parent controller, you should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730799/rotating-the-iphone-and-instantiating-a-new-uiviewcontroller).

Also make sure to return YES to shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation from all of your subviews.

Your assumption of setting shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation to return YES will **not** prevent didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation from being run.

Hope this helps a little.